# How to automatically crop out diagrams from a engineering drawing image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Here's the sample image I am using:

[image: pin1.png]

I'm basically trying to automatically extract diagrams from similarly structured engineering drawings by removing non diagram contours, however since the table doesn't have continuously flowing data, it treats it as if it were another diagram and keeps it within the cropped region.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("pin1.png")
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(
    blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20, 10))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if w/h > 2 and area > 10000:
        cv2.drawContours(dilate, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)

boxes = []
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    boxes.append([x, y, x+w, y+h])

boxes = np.asarray(boxes)
x = np.min(boxes[:, 0])
y = np.min(boxes[:, 1])
w = np.max(boxes[:, 2]) - x
h = np.max(boxes[:, 3]) - y

cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 2)
cropped_region = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]


cv2.namedWindow("original", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("thresh", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("dilate", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("cropped_region", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('cropped_region', cropped_region)
cv2.imwrite("Cropped1.png", cropped_region)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I'm not sure how to go about making the contour filter search for the table instead of lines of text since I'm new to this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60T4.png)

Comment: so what is your expected output?

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Here's the expected output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60T4.png

Comment: @TyronGlaen Does the image has the same dimensions always?

Comment: @Bilal No, not always, they vary slightly by 100-200 px at both height and width

Comment: @TyronGlaen Then the plot always has the same ratio??

Comment: @Bilal Most of the drawings that I've seen online (and the sample) follow the same ratio but there are a few that do deviate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly find a method of automatic detection.

I however made use of template matching and added 4 templates to an array and it worked well enough for me.

I followed this [doc](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)